# Error in MCMCglmm: Missing Values in the Fixed Predictors - But I have no missing values

Tags: missing-data, mcmc

I am trying to run the following code -

```
mod1 <- MCMCglmm(y ~ a + b + c + d + e + f, random =~ g + h + n, data=dat1, verbose = FALSE)
```

When I run it in R, I get the error message "missing values in the fixed predictors". I do have some missing values in 2 of my independent variables, however, I have used the na.omit() function to omit these rows. I am not sure why I am getting this error message or how to move forward - any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is my first time posting on stack overflow and am happy to provide additional info that may be needed to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi Alex! I am having the same issue - have you been able to solve it?

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, I haven't had any luck yet :(

Comment: I ended up removing the NA entries by following the advice here: https://rpubs.com/jmichaelrosenberg/477833 (Section 2B) and the error message did not appear again after :)